Blocking duplicate IP addresses within network
I have a self contained network, which at the moment consists of 13 machines with PLCs connected to three unmanaged TL-SG105S switches in one room.
The idea was to connect a laptop to one switch, and then be able to connect to the other thirteen machines around the room via ethernet, to download program updates, get backups etc. without having to cart a laptop around the room. The throughout required on this network can be incredibly slow, there will be a few kB of data every so often.
Each machine has an ethernet device within it, that doesn't need to communicate with anything outside of the machine, i.e. past the PLC, so I  put the ethernet device within the PLC on a different subnet, 192.168.10.XX, instead of 192.168.0.XX.
Unfortunately, I have  discovered that while the PLC has two ethernet ports, these are entirely transparent, and the internal devices are communicating with each other machine in the room as well, causing all kinds of issues.
I am not sure of the best solution; I was thinking some kind of IP filtering would be the best solution, if each of the switches (which I am fairly certain these ones can't do) only forward requests from the 192.168.0.XX subnet, that would solve the issue, but is there a better way?
It would be fairly trivial for me to find the offending devices MAC addresses if this would be better?
I can (I suspect I will have to) buy different devices, but I'm not sure what specifications I should be looking for.
This network will never be connected to the wider world at all, so there is no security risk from that point of view.
Many thanks for your help!
Edit: Here is a diagram, to make it clearer (Pretend that there are three switches and thirteen PLCs):

The problem is that device A can (and is) talking to PLC B and PLC C, and so is device B etc.
I know it is not a great setup, but with the amount of data flow, it seemed the simplest and cheapest.
(Oh, and the User device only has one network card, and so can either be on the network with the PLCs, or the internet, but never both together)
I forgot to add, everything on the network has a static IP.

it in would be fairly trivial for me to find the offending devices MAC addresses if this would be better? yes, that would be a minimum requirement...

If you can't stop the PLCs from bridging that unwanted traffic to the switch, there's nothing you can do with those unmanaged switches.
Most managed switches provide at least one of several ways for filtering that unwanted traffic, including

blacklisting MAC addresses
private VLANs or source-port filtering
VLAN separation with routing (L3 only)
VLAN separation with trunking to the admin PC
IPv4 or MAC ACLs


There's a nearly identical managed switch for the same price. TL-SG105E

I've ordered one of those, and I will try it tomorrow; hopefully it solves my problems!

I 've set up VLAN separation with trunking and that appears to be working well, thank you for the help.

The real answer is separation of the networks.
Put in another NIC in the PLC and use that NIC to communicate with the device.
If you don't want separation, then don't have separation - and threat it as one subnet with unique adresses.

I'm sorry, I'm confused, how would this help?

The PLC is doing the bridging, not the PC and I can't add a new NIC to the PLC, or am I missing something?

You probably can - most support some form of CP card. Can you present a drawing of your network to help understand it better? You have to rework things in some fashion; adding a CP card is one way to handle this.

I've added a diagram, hopefully this makes it clearer

As I said - add network cards on the PLC's to segregate networks, or configure distinct IP's.

I've had a look and my PLCs don't have additional CP cards for ethernet/IP communications. I assume by configure distinct IPs you mean change the IPs of A, B etc. so they are all distinct? Unfortunately, the IPs of the devices are in the programs in the PLCs, which would then make version control a nightmare across the devices.

What PLC is it? Normally you can get add-on cards for most PLCs.

A Unitronics Unistream https://www.unitronicsplc.com/programmable-controllers-unistream-series/
